# Angular i18n internationalization of Component-Inputs

Tags: angular, internationalization

In our new Angular 4 App we use the integrated i18n features to translate the application. Translation done while AOT compilation. General translation features are working well, but how do you handle the translation of Component-Inputs:

`<accordion-group [heading]="model.type == 3 ? 'Heading 1' : 'Heading 2'">....<accordion-group>`

We need to translate the [heading]. The code within the accordion-group is the same, so duplication is not an option.

So what is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Built-in internationalization API in Angular4 still looks weird for me. We use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in our project and all translations are placed in language files. (For us those files are in `.toml` format and loaded by `toml-loader`.) In mentioned library you could achieve your goal this way:

```html
<accordion-group
    [heading]="(model.type == 3 ? 'Heading_1' : 'Heading_2') | translate">
...
<accordion-group>
```

So if it is an option for you - I would migrate...

Comment: Is there any way using the builtin API? It feels a bit clunky currently, but ok if used with AOT compilation. If possible I would avoid adding additional dependencies to the project (....there are already enought...).

Comment: I don't know is it possible with builtin API, since I was always using `ngx-translate` even before i18n was released and didn't have any thought to move from. I strongly recommend to use this library instead if you can. There are probably less relevant dependencies in the project to get rid of ;)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way with the built in API?

Comment: 2 years later `ngx-translate` is still sufficient and easier to use ;)